# Force Android WebView to open external links in default browser

Tags: android, webview

I am using the following code found on stackoverflow to make an app for my website.
It works, the website loads, but all links are loading inside the app.
I dont want links like facebook, youtube or any other external links to open inside my app.
How can I open external links outside my webview app ?
I am new to android coding, so if you can edit my code and post a full example answer, it will be great help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.sitename.com");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }


    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        if((String.valueOf(request.getUrl())).contains("facebook")) {
            view.loadUrl(String.valueOf(request.getUrl()));
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What have you confirmed? Is it calling your callback or not? I believe shouldOverrideUrlLoading is only called if you set a configuration within the WebSettings.

Comment: @JoxTraex, I have no idea what I am doing, if you can provide a full working code, that will be great!

Comment: Should may read this and update your post with your debugging results - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug and also read the docuemtnation to know what you should expect. Maybe also ask some specific questions as well.

Comment: The reason I ask the above is because we don't know what exactly you're looking for and what you're seeing logically from within the app. Knowing the behavior will help you/us debug.